# Saving text effects as graphic styles in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

I created text effects a few times before and tried to save them as graphic styles by sliding the finished text into the graphic styles panel. But when I do this I just get a blank white box. Its the same when I try to load it back into the graphic styles panel from the library.

I recently watched a tutorial on creating graphic styles and I noticed the style was created using the appearance panel which I'm still learning to use.

What am I doing wrong?
Is creating in the appearance panel the only way I can save a graphic style?